# What's the work done by a spring on a block when it moves from extreme to mean position?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, spring, conventions

I really don't know where am I doing it wrong, but block when it moves towards mean position displacement will be along the force right, so the force acting on block will be $+fxdx$

Integrating we get 
$$\frac{k}{2}(x_f^2-x_i^2)<0$$

Since $x_f$ would be smaller than $x_i$ in the case when we take $x=0$ as origin. Why is the work showing up as negative?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! You need to clarify your question: is X positive, and the spring pushing it towards the negative? (You can guess that you have some sort of sign problem, and being clearer will likely show where.)

Comment: Spring is pushing towards negative and not reached mean

Comment: @YashSinghal I have edited my answer to include a clearer and mathematical point of view. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question arises because of a subtlety involved in the choice of variables and infinitesimals we use in the definite integration to find the work done by the force.

If the block is at the coordinate $x$ and is moving towards the origin then the work done by the spring on it during the small interval of time in which the block travels a *distance* of $dl$ is clearly $kx\ dl$. And of course, this $kx\ dl$ is positive because as you have noticed the block is moving in the direction of the force. But the point is that you are choosing the variable $x$ to represent the coordinate of the block. Thus during a travel of distance $dl$, the change in the coordinate of the block (i.e  $ dx$  ) is not actually equal to $dl$ in this case because the coordinate value is decreasing so "the change in its coordinate value corresponding to a distance travel of $dl$ " = $dx$ = $-dl$. Thus the work done $W$ = $ \int kx\ dl$ = $ - \int kx\ dx$ with proper limits. (i.e. from $x=x_i$ to $x=x_f$) Now the things will settle.

**Edit:**

A rather elegant and mathematical way to calculate the work done can be considered like this:

$dW\ =\ F\ * infinitesimal\ small\ displacement$

Now,

the force here is $-kx$ (because it is in negative X direction);

the displacement is by definition $dx$

(which can be either in positive or negative X direction, but both the cases are taken care for just by writing the displacement to be $dx$ i.e. if you want to write it in the terms of distance then you have to particularly are whether you should write $dx\  =\  -|dx|\  or\  dx\ =\  |dx|$. But we do not need it. We have the formula for the work done which just involves the displacement term. So we are relieved.).

So $ dW = -\  kx\ dx$

So $ W = -\  \frac{k}{2}(x^2_f - x^2_i)$

Thus clearly $W>0$ as $x_f  < x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice,  we know $$x_f<x_i$$ $$\iff x_f^2<x_i^2\ \  \ \ \ ( \forall \ \ \ x_i, \ x_f\ge0)$$
$$\iff x_f^2-x_i^2<0$$$$\iff k(x_f^2-x_i^2)<0 \ \  \ \ \ ( \forall \ \ \ k>0)$$

Now, the work done by the spring on the block is $$\int_{x_i}^{x_f}kx\ dx=\frac{1}{2}k(x_f^2-x_i^2)<0$$ 
Thus, the work done by the spring on the block is negative. It also represents that if we take $x=0$ as the origin then the displacement $x$ of the block is decreasing from $x_i$ to $x_f$ (i.e. negative x-direction). Now,

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sign of the expression

$$\frac12 \;k \; (x_f^2 - x_i^2)$$

depends on your choice of coordinate system. If you put $x_f=0$, then the result is negative; if you put $x_i=0$ then the result is positive. But the work done should be the same, regardless of the choice of coordinates.

So what is happening?

Simply, when we say $F = -kx$ we have implicitly defined $x$ *relative to the equilibrium position*: in other words, $x=0$ when $F=0$.

Now if $x_f$ is the equilibrium position, then we know that the block is trying to move to this position - if you try to hold it, then the block will do work on you (you are pulling on the block in a direction opposite to the motion). And indeed the expression evaluates to a negative number.

If instead $x_i$ is the equilibrium position, then you are moving *away* from equilibrium: so the force and the displacement are in the same direction, and the work done is positive.